# Could I transform the python code generated from pyuic back to a ui file?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

PyQt could tranform Qt ui file to python module through: `pyuic5 file.ui > file.py`. But could I turn the way the other around? Something like: `pyuic5 file.py > file.ui`?

Answer (score 1):

I don´t know about a tool that do what you want, but surely you could manually build a ui file by reading the generated py.  The generated py file is very descriptive.

If is the case that you lose your file.ui, this is the approach you should follow, don´t lose any time rigth now building such tool. You should focus in getting your project up again.

Another advise, use a [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system for your projects!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just recreate ui files in Qt Designer according to the py files.

Answer (score 0):

There is [QAbstractFormBuilder](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractformbuilder.html), which can be used to save widgets to a `ui` file.

That obviously can't convert *everything* in the python module, but it might allow you to save an instance of the main widget, and perhaps recover most of the original `ui` file. I say "perhaps", because I have not personaly had much success with it on the few occasions I've tried it - but hopefully others may be luckier.

Comment: I don't think that I get your point correctly. But the problem was solved by creating the ui files manually in Qt Designer according the py files. Thanks again.